# Question about ROS implementation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have base questions about ROS.
The questions are:

1. What is Logical basic unit in ROS?
2. What is Execution basic unit in ROS?
3. Has ROS Applied RMI middleware?

Thanks for answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45166/question-about-ros-implementation/) by [needhelpros](https://answers.ros.org/users/3320/needhelpros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello and welcome,
I think you should first try to read the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) to get started with ROS.

*Per se*, ROS does not enforce any robotics component model. So you are free to choose whatever models suits you. There have been attempts in the past to provide models for nodes behavior[1]. Therefore the question 1 and 2 have little sense in the ROS framework (not that having a model is not interesting, it is just not what ROS provides).
The answer to question 3 is "no" (AFAIK).

[1] I am thinking here of [driver_base](http://ros.org/wiki/driver_base) but please do not learn ROS by trying to use this node first as it is not actively maintained

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you taken a look at ROS [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/)?

I would recommend you to read the following:

- [ROS/Introduction](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction)
- [ROS/Concepts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts)
- [ROS/Higer Level Concepts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Higher-Level%20Concepts)

Regarding your questions...

1. What is Logical basic unit in ROS?

   I would say: messages and topics
2. What is Execution basic unit in ROS?

   Could be: Nodes and nodelets
3. Has ROS Applied RMI middleware?

   Sorry, I have no answer for that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4